# How to encrypt a file via AES-256-CBC with a password instead of a key and iv in the openssl library?

Tags: c++, openssl

I need to encrypt a file via `AES-256-CBC` but with **textual password** instead of a key and iv. I think, that there is no any way to do that so I must convert my textual password to the byte array, expand it somehow to the key length and treat it as a key, and then.. I don't know what to do with the initialization vector. So the question is how to correctly do this?

P.S. Note please that I need to do this not with command line openssl but with the library.

Comment: Since you are not working in C, and you need command help... Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww what are you reading? I am asking about c++ openssl usage in the question, not the command line.

Comment: *"what are you reading?"* - your comment on Wagner's answer.

Comment: @jww looks like you have got moderator permissions without knowing how to use them.

Comment: *... looks like you have got moderator permissions without knowing how to use them"* - Perhaps, but the privileges were not used. What is the moderation you object to?

Comment: @jww I need a c++ solution here. The question I have asked in the comments is just a little sub question, it is not related to the question so that you may think I have changed my original question. Also, you wanna close the proper question for something in the comments lol, you are making a decision based on unrelated things. This is wrong. The question is correct, the same as the answer to it. There are not problems here.

Comment: Thanks. I've got to admit I am kind of confused. I did not moderate the question, and I did not move to close it. I don't have access to the diamond mod tools so I don't know about some of the other moderation that may have occurred. As far as I can tell, there are no close votes on it. What are you talking about with respect to moderation and close votes?

Comment: @jww thank you too then :) I can’t see the question status via mobile application, so I have thought you voted for closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victor, you are in the right direction. The password, in this case, is just something that you can hash and obtain the key that will be used for encrypting with AES. The IV (initialization vector) is something that can be public and is not part of your password. The function `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()` has a parameter for it. It will be something like this:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX cryptContext;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&cryptContext);
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&cryptContext, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), 0, key, iv);
EVP_EncryptUpdate(&cryptContext, output, &outputLength, input, inputLength);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&cryptContext);
```

Use the function `EVP_BytesToKey()` in order to "convert" your password to a key:

```
uint8_t key[AES_256_CBC_KEY_SIZE];
uint8_t iv[AES_256_CBC_IV_SIZE];
EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha256(), salt, password, passwordLength, 1, key, iv);
```

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer! But it turns out I also have to know how to do this via command line openssl (I have to encrypt via cmd and to decrypt via the same password via the library). Does `openssl -enc aes-256-cbc -pass` does exactly this?

Comment: I have found the answer to my little subquestion above. Yes, it does exactly this (according to the source code and the `openssl -p` output but instead of `sha256` digest it uses `EVP_md5` (if you have not specified it explicitly)). Thank you again.

Comment: awesome. I would not know the command line. But I am sure there's a way to to exact the same (and other combinations) via command line. OpenSSL is high detailed in its command line options. I would just tell: "I dont know, but for sure there's a way" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is convert a text password for use with the new createCipher createDecipher APIs (which add "iv"), then the conversion info is clear (see Wagner's answer in the other response).

However, the *reason* these APIs are being deprecated is essential to understanding why you should use them differently. For that reason, I'd recommend reading something like this strong article on encryption using the latest Node APIs. Short article, but very clear and yet secure approach.

http://vancelucas.com/blog/stronger-encryption-and-decryption-in-node-js/

I say this because it can be deceptively easy to move from one API to another without understanding the reason for the change, and thus, lose the benefit of the intended change.

In this post and the link given, the platform in question is Node, but the issue is the same on any platform. You shouldn't treat the IV as just a template parameter that you give away to the user. Make it random. The benefits of this are explained in the link, as I've said.